# 14.04 Explore Files on Android via Bluetooth

Tags: usb, 14.04, bluetooth, file-sharing

My laptop (Ubuntu 14.04) has a built-in Bluetooth support and I've successfully paired it to my Android smartphone.

I DON'T want to send files from laptop to smartphone or vice versa. Nor do I want to connect via USB cable.

**What I'm trying to do is to explore/read files from my laptop on my smartphone via Bluetooth, like it's connected with an USB cable.**

Any idea how to do this?